# AngularJS ng-if with a true or false object value

Tags: angularjs

Not entirely sure why this isn't working. I'm trying to hide a `col` is the value of driveThru is false OR equals to 'N'.

`ng-if="location.driveThru === false || location.driveThru === 'N'"`

However the `=== false` isn't working and I cant determine why.

Comment: is it false or null?

Comment: it comes back as `driveThru: true`

Comment: or `driveThru: false`

Comment: Using the property name `location` is fraught with peril, since it's also a property of the `window` global variable. It might be better to change the name of that to `loc` or `somethingLocation` (replace `something` with a meaningful phrase from your domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its a boolean change as ,

```
"!location.driveThru' || location.driveThru === 'N'
```

and === with string enclosed in quotes if its a string a follows,

```
ng-if="location.driveThru === 'false' || location.driveThru === 'N'"
```

Comment: Its a boolean value

Comment: then try jjust "!location.driveThru' || location.driveThru === 'N'

Comment: @HereticMonkey by mistake, now it should be fine